# How to access shared network files in Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, samba, lan

How to access shared network files in Ubuntu Touch? In Android I use ES File Explorer to access files on a Raspberry Pi shared over LAN only.

Comment: Try this, sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=$UID,gid=$(id -g) share ~/host

Comment: I think there is no UI or app for that yet. And I think we will have to wait at least one year more for Ubuntu Touch to become great for everyone.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions but I've gone back to Android for now. I'll try again try soon...

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu Touch File Manager now has built in Samba support, just click "Network" under "Places". A little bit slow and sometimes buggy, but a big step forward... For tranfering large files I have to keep the screen active.